# jQuery li expanding with more text

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, custom-data-attribute

Been trying to get these li elements to expand individually, one at a time when they are moused over:  http://jsfiddle.net/LU5dW/1/ (using `data-text` attribute)

And another http://jsfiddle.net/LU5dW/ using a span `.menu_text` class.  Can't get either one here to work.

jQuery Code for `data-text` attribute using `.append`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#menu a").hover(function() {
         $(this).append($(this).children.eq(0).html("<span>" + $(this).children.eq(0).data('text') + "</span>")).css({width: 0}).stop(true, true).animate({width: "show"}, 700);
            }, function() {
                    $(this).children(":last-child").stop(true, true).animate({width: "hide"}, 700).remove();
            });
});
```

jQuery Code for `.menu_text` class with a `display: none` by default:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
     $("#menu a").hover(function() {
                $(this).children(".menu_text").stop(true, true).animate({width: "show"}, 700);
            }, function() {
                $(this).children(".menu_text").stop(true, true).animate({width: "hide"}, 700);
            });
});
```

Could really use another set of eyes on this one.  Thanks guys :)

Problem is I am trying to get each item to expand on `mouseenter` and than collapse on `mouseleave`, but not having any luck with either of these approaches.  The `data-text` approach is throwing an error that I'm not catching somewhere...

***EDIT***

Here is another approach now using the `data-text` attribute, almost works, but it expands all of the `li` elements instead of just 1 of them... arggg:  http://jsfiddle.net/LU5dW/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#menu li").hover(function() {
         $(this).children("a").append("<span>" + $(this).children("a").children(':first-child').data('text') + "</span>").hide().stop(true, true).animate({width: "show"}, 700);
            }, function() {
                    $(this).children("a").children(":last-child").stop(true, true).animate({width: "hide"}, 700).remove();
            });
});
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: I'm trying to animate the width of each element when moused over, but it isn't working...

Comment: The `data-text` approach isn't appending anything at all onto it.

Comment: Ok, got the `data-text` approach working now, but seems to be a problem that all `li` tags are expanding now instead of individually.

Comment: Is JavaScript a requirement? Assuming a user will have a pointing device (and therefore can use CSS's `:hover`), [this can be done with CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LU5dW/6/).

Comment: @DavidThomas - Would be nice, but it should work in IE 8 as well... so I don't think that solution works in IE 8 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding `float: left` and `clear: both` to the `li` style.
Also added `overflow: hidden` and a `height` to the `a` style to eliminate the text from creeping up as the `li` are expanding.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/baacke/LU5dW/12/)